# Load a webworker based on the relative path of the caller when the caller is embedded in a Html file

Tags: javascript, file, web-worker

I have 2 javascript files. One is named "index.js" and the other "worker.js".

index.js will be embedded into all the pages of my website (meaning different hierarchy's). I need to call "worker.js" from index.js when any of these pages are loaded.

The problem is index.js thinks its own path is the path of the page it's embedded in. So if my file directory looks like this:

```
index.html
├───JS
│   ├───index.js
│   ├───worker.js
├───otherPage
│   ├───newPage.html
```

When I'm in the "index.html" file I can use the path "JS/worker.js" to load the worker from index.js.

However, when I'm in "newPage.html" I would need to use the path "../JS/worker.js" to load the worker.

This means each time "index.js" is placed on a page it would have to be edited to find the location of worker.js. How can I avoid this and use the local path of "index.js" to resolve the path of worker.js against?

Comment: you could load your javascript file through a relative path starting from the root of your website?

Comment: @Icepickle you mean using an absolute path including the domain name? Otherwise I'm not sure how to load via a relative path starting from the root.

Comment: Well, seeing that you are not using a single page application, you would have something like `/JS/worker.js` which would point to `http://yourdomain/JS/worker.js`, however if you would then have your site published under `http://yourdomain/website` you would have to change it to `/website/JS/worker.js`. I guess it kinda depends on how your current implementation looks, in an SPA, your code would be loaded once and that would be it